# Show Links to "Related Categories" in WooCommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

I'm looking to show related categories in my product information - similar to the way that related products is shown but with showing the link to the category archive instead of individual products.

For example, on a Wash Trough product the related categories would be "Taps" and "Mirrors" and would display the links to these on the product page.

Is this possible?  I've looked at a lot of plugins that extend the related products section, but they only add the ability to show products of different categories rather than the category pages themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work this out.  I created a relationship field in PODs to link product to product_cat and then created this code to display the related categories using a shortcode.

```
    function gr_related_categories(){
    //get Pods object for current post
    $pod = pods( 'product', get_the_id() );

//get the value for the relationship field
$related = $pod->field( 'related_categories' );

if ( ! empty( $related ) ) {
    $rows.='<div style=" display: grid; grid-gap: 5px; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr)); grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 350px);">';
    foreach ( $related as $rel ) { 
        $id = $rel[ 'term_id' ];
        $term=get_term($id, 'product_cat');

        $name = $rel['name'];
        $slug = $rel['slug'];
        $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image=wp_get_attachment_image($thumbnail_id, 'full');
        $url=get_term_link($term);

        $rows.= ' <div style="width:250px; height:350px; margin: 20px auto; border:solid 2px #5500B5; text-align:center; "><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">'.$image.'<br>'.$name.'</a></div>';
    } //end of foreach
    $rows.= '</div>';

} //endif ! empty ( $related );
return $rows;
}

add_shortcode('gr_related_categories', 'gr_related_categories');
```